# Where is this running executable getting its command arguments from?

Tags: .net, vb.net, command-line-arguments, executable

I'm helping out a colleague who is on holiday. One of the apps on his roster is a Windows service which manages a program that processes Visio files. The program is started by the service but, if/when it fails it can be manually restarted by the .exe file - i.e. *not* via the commandline.

The program is picking up two pieces of data from the standard args parameter (type: string[]) that is passed to the `main` method but I can't for the life of me figure out where these arguments are being taken from as it is being run via a double click on the .exe icon and not the commandline. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: what do you mean by `the .exe icon`?  A Shortcut?  If so examine the properties which can include command line params

Comment: Do they have default values if a value is not passed in?

Comment: The "target" could very well be doing it. If it has the parameters expressed (outside the double-quotes) then the program will be shown those parameters, just like a command-line argument. Edit: right-click executable -> Properties -> "Target" field

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just run the .exe from a shortcut (right click on exe and select create short cut) and then inside the properties add the params eg.

[image]

They should then be accessible as the args[].

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm not trying to run it with the args[], trying to figure out *where* they're coming from at runtime.